# Popup to appear and close with a target process

Tags: vbscript, popup, hta

I am trying to use the code [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575588/show-message-dialog-while-executing/17951647#17951647), and with some tweaking for HTA. It works to a point:

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
```

changes into:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
```

The popup comes up, but it won't go away until I click it. I need it appear when a process is running, then disappear when it ends. Why is my execution failing to do this?

```
ProgressMsg "Copying, Please wait.", "File Being Copied" 
strCMD = "cmd.exe /c robocopy " & strLocalSemesterCourse & " " & strServerSemesterCourse &" " & strFileName & " /LOG+:" & strLogName & " /V /FP /TEE" 
nReturn = objShell.Run(strCMD, 1, true) 
ProgressMsg "", "Finished"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `objProgressMsg` as a **global** variable for this to work:

```
Dim objProgressMsg
...
ProgressMsg "Copying, Please wait.", "File Being Copied" 
strCMD = "cmd.exe /c robocopy " & strLocalSemesterCourse & " " _
  & strServerSemesterCourse &" " & strFileName & " /LOG+:" & strLogName _
  & " /V /FP /TEE" 
nReturn = objShell.Run(strCMD, 1, true) 
ProgressMsg "", "Finished"
```

Without the global variable, `ProgressMsg()` will use a **local** variable `objProgressMsg`. Local variables don't retain their value after the function exits, so the variable will be empty every time you call the function.

Comment: HI - Thanks for the help. I was able to get it to work with your help.